# Where to store my custom Python modules on GCP so they can be accessed by different GCP services?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone have any good suggestions for where I can store my custom Python modules on Google Cloud Platform?

I have a bunch of modules that I would like to access from the different GCP services I am using (App Engine, Compute Engine, Cloud Functions etc), without having to copy the Python files and upload to the service's Python environment each time.

I was thinking GCS could be an option but then I am not sure how I would then get the module into, say Cloud Functions or App Engine?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The code will eventually need to be written to your service's local storage. Python does not access code remotely during execution unless you write your code to do so (download the module and then execute). Package your code as modules and publish to PyPI and then add them as dependencies. When you deploy a service, your modules will be downloaded.

Comment: You have an [alpha feature](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/quickstart) on Google Cloud to host your private PyPi on your project. Never tested.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - That is a nice feature for private modules. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting, indeed. Thank you.